# I cannot post questions

Tags: bug, status-norepro, questions

I can't post questions on the website, I click post and it takes me to the "/questions/ask/submit" page. Nothing happens after that.

Please help!

Comment: Try reloading the submit page. It often happens, and it has worked for me.

Comment: Tried it, it gives me a page not found. :(

Comment: Is javascript enabled? Try clearing your cache.

Comment: Is this still an issue? Are you getting any javascript or other errors in the developer tools (F12 in chrome)?